# Android: Expected resource of type id

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm having a strange problem in Android Studio.

I have got my activity_chords_list.xml file with a `RecyclerView` inside it that looks like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/chords_recycler"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_top"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />
```

But in my `onCreate()` method it isn't recognised:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chords_list);

    chordsList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.layout.chords_recycler);
```

and I get the following two errors:

- `Expected resource of type ID`
- `cannot resolve symbol chords_recycler`

Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: You need to add relative stacktrace on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
android:id="@id/chords_recycler"
```

for

```
android:id="@+id/chords_recycler"
```

From [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html):

> The plus-symbol (+) means that this is a new resource name that must be created and added to our resources (in the R.java file).

And you need to access it using `R.id.chords_recycler`:

```
chordsList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.chords_recycler);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use this:

```
 chordsList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.chords_recycler);
```

Comment: Basically the same as @Antonio said, only he had an **earlier** answer and also the fuller one, since he explained the `+id` difference as well.

Comment: @Vucko The `Lino` answer is accepted because OP has write wrong thing in question so I and antonio give answer on `Id`.

Comment: Antoio covered both things as far as I can see :)